# Prior art shared with the USPTO

Tags: prior-art, uspto, examiner

The USPTO started allowing the public to submit prior art just last year. How will the public know if prior art that is submitted through the third party submission system was used to reject a patent application? Has any prior art submitted by the public been used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of December 5, 2012, the USPTO had received 3rd Party Submissions in 111 pending applications. I have listed these here:

APN
13057428
13145379
12829968
12940276
13036151
13409599
12832713
12914510
12940265
13367018
13403496
12793132
13133905
12027158
13146703
13284337
12901113
13276498
12949867
13030014
13061072
13238728
12911418
12987982
13308698
13465789
13270518
12708697
12980609
13198108
13205610
13370103
13330442
13331182
13331192
13027232
13370480
13458626
12896664
13072724
13212266
13214397
13331786
13062414
13444511
13460635
11946818
12890208
12890259
13061068
13062106
13316963
13325149
12882610
13143163
13193319
12908761
13129175
13281126
13179249
13328621
12946772
13052381
13401848
13039184
13280490
13354282
13354286
12950669
13043011
13052666
13214230
12731825
13101072
13280914
13280932
12899731
13280536
13331998
13354244
13354284
13354290
12899972
13280843
13413451
13536353
13196835
12856888
13092606
13305290
13064390
13281615
13487297
11883950
13486014
13016460
13126818
13161311
13208672
13273864
13160297
12726539
13024072
13069446
13265786
13319070
13551246
12917202
13376021
12895942
13493787

Answer (score 4):

Paul Morgan has a good article posted here on this subject:

http://www.patentlyo.com/patent/2012/01/guest-post-should-you-submit-third-party-prior-art.html

If the prior art is used to reject a patent application, it will appear in the prosecution history. If an Office Action contains a rejection relying on that prior art, that prior art will be listed as cited art and discussed in the body of the Office Action.  You can access on-line prosecution histories and filed documents for pending patent applications through public PAIR:

http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair

Answer (score 1):

Denis Crouch put together a nice list of the 111 pending applications for which the USPTO had received 3rd party submissions as of Dec, 2012.

I was curious as to:

1. The subject of the pending applications which had stimulated 3rd party submission to the USPTO; and
2. The assignee of these applications

The top three applicants were Lockheed Martin (5 applications), Valens Semiconductor (5 applications) and Ineos Bio (5 applications).  Very few if any of the applications were related to software.  **Software is a technology area where StackOverflow can help a lot by soliciting, organizing and submitting third party prior art to the USPTO.**  The market doesn't seem to be doing this on its own yet.

Here is the list of pending applications, the assignees, the titles and the abstracts. (Abstracts truncated to fit StackExchange).

**US20120058247A1**     ZHEJIANG GREEN WORLD BIO TECH ENGINEERING CO LTD | EPC BEIJING NATURAL PRODUCTS INC `REBAUDIOSIDE A AND STEVIOSIDE COMPOSITIONS`   The invention describes  stevia composi

**US20120081108A1**     WESTINGHOUSE ELECTRIC CORP  `NONDESTRUCTIVE INSPECTION METHOD FOR A HEAT EXCHANGER EMPLOYING ADAPTIVE NOISE THRESHOLDING`   A method of eddy current testing for flaws in a tube is provided that includes passing an eddy current probe through the tube and obtaining eddy current data for a 
 **US20120117293A1**     VALENS SEMICONDUCTOR LTD    `USB host adaptor for initiating a USB connection over a non-USB network`   Initiating, by USB host adaptors, USB connections over a non-USB network, including the steps of: Connecting non-collocated USB h   
 **US20120117292A1**     VALENS SEMICONDUCTOR LTD    `Method and system for initiating distinct USB connections over a network`   Connecting USB devices with USB hosts over distinct network paths, including the following steps: Connecting USB hosts wi   
 **US20120117278A1**     VALENS SEMICONDUCTOR LTD    `Method and system for partial USB enumeration and edge initiation`   Initiating USB-over-network connections based on partial USB enumeration, including the steps of: Discovering U 
 **US20120117277A1**     VALENS SEMICONDUCTOR LTD    `Method and system for USB addressing by a network adaptor`   Addressing, by USB host adaptors, packets conveying USB data over a non-USB network, including the steps of: Connecting USB hosts   
 **US20120117276A1**     VALENS SEMICONDUCTOR LTD    `USB device adaptor for initiating a USB connection over a non-USB network`   Initiating, by USB device adaptors, USB connections over a non-USB network, including the steps of: Connecting non-collocated USB   
 **US20120068157A1**     US GOV SEC NAVY `Transistor Having Graphene Base`   A transistor device having a graphene base for the transport of electrons into a collector is provided. The transistor consists of a heterostructure comprising an electron e   
 **US20110212467A1**     UNIV SOUTHERN CALIFORNIA    `INHIBITORS OF dUTPase`   Evidence demonstrating that elevated expression of dUTPase protects breast cancer cells from the expansion of the intracellular     
 **US20120107247A1**     UNIV NEW JERSEY MED `Proteins Expressed by Mycobacterium Tuberculosis and not by BCG and their Use as Diagnostic Reagents and Vaccines`   The present invention is directed to reage  
 **US20120158354A1**     TROXLER ELECTRONIC LAB INC  `METHODS, SYSTEMS, AND COMPUTER PROGRAM PRODUCTS FOR LOCATING AND TRACKING OBJECTS`   A system for locating and tracking an object is provided. The system includes a measuring device configured to det  
 **US20080298695A1**     TOSHIBA KK  `MOTION VECTOR DETECTING APPARATUS, MOTION VECTOR DETECTING METHOD AND INTERPOLATION FRAME CREATING APPARATUS`   According to one embodiment, a motion vector detecting apparatus performs block matching of 
 **US20120021913A1**     SYNGENTA CROP PROTECTION LLC    `TURF SAFE GRANULAR HERBICIDE FORMULATIONS`   The present invention relates to    
 **US20120214386A1**     SUGINO MACHINED LTD `ABRASIVE WATER JET PROCESSING MACHINE`   An abrasive water jet processing machine for jetting a fluid and performing a cutting includes a fluid supply device, an abrasive supply device, an injection pressure control  
 **US20120195640A1**     STATIC CONTROL COMPONENTS INC   `Systems & Methods for Remanufacturing Imaging Components`   A drive gear for a generally cylindrical imaging component. T   
 **US20120214125A1**     SS WHITE BURS INC   `ENDODONTIC BURS, KITS, AND METHODS FOR USING ENDODONTIC BURS`   A conical dental bur for endodontic procedures, including exploration, deep troughing, enlargement of orifices, and canal navigation is pres    
 **US20120239808A1**     SIPCO LLC   `SYSTEMS AND METHODS FOR CONTROLLING COMMUNICATION BETWEEN A HOST COMPUTER AND COMMUNICATION DEVICES`   An exemplary embodiment of the present invention provides a site controller for use in a    
 **US20120111396A1**     SIONYX INC  `Photovoltaic Devices and Associated Methods`   A method for making a semiconductor device includes providing a s   
 **US20110165231A1**     SCIOTEC DIAGNOSTIC TECHNOLOGIES GMBH    `Treatment of Fructose Malabsorption`   The present invention relates to    
 **US20080254475A1**     SANOFI AVENTIS DEUTSCHLAND  `NEMATODES AS MODEL ORGANISMS FOR THE INVESTIGATION OF NEURODEGENERATIVE DISEASES, IN PARTICULAR PARKINSONS DISEASE, USES AND METHODS FOR THE DISCOVERY OF SUBSTANCES AND GENES WHICH CAN USED IN THE TREATMENT OF THE ABOVE DISEASE STATES AND IDENTIFICATION OF A NEMATODE GENE`   The invention relates to nematodes as model organisms for the investigation of neurodegenerative diseases, in particular, Parkinsons disease, uses and meth 
 **US20120129227A1**     SANDIA CORP | UNIV CALIFORNIA   `THERMOSTABLE CELLULASES, AND MUTANTS THEREOF, CAPABLE OF HYDROLYZING CELLULOSE IN IONIC LIQUID`   The present invention provides for a composition comprising an ionic liquid and a thermostable cell 
 **US20110088987A1**     SAMSONITE IP HOLDINGS S A R L   `LUGGAGE PANEL WITH INTEGRATED CARRY HANDLE FOR SOFT-SIDE TYPE LUGGAGE CASES`   Luggage cases of the soft-side construction are perceived to be lighter than hard-side cases. However, many rigidifying elements in s   
 **US20120121915A2**     SAINT GOBAIN    `PROCESS FOR OBTAINING GLASS AND GLASS OBTAINED`   The object of the invention is a continuous method for obtaining glass, comprising steps consisting of charging raw materials upstream of a furnace, along which a p    
 **US20110281078A1**     SAINT GOBAIN    `TRANSPARENT GLASS SUBSTRATE AND PROCESS FOR MANUFACTURING SUCH A SUBSTRATE`   This transparent glass substrate has at least one face which is provided with a texturing formed by a plurality of geometric features in relief relative to a g 
 **US20110135938A1**     SAINT GOBAIN    `PROCESS FOR OBTAINING GLASS AND GLASS OBTAINED`   "The object of the invention is a continuous method for obtaining glass, comprising steps consisting of charging raw materials upstream of a furnace, along wh" 
 **US20110250338A1**     PEPSICO INC `Adsorption Purification Of Caramel`   A process of purifying a caramel color solution comprisi    
 **US20120165885A1**     PACESETTER INC  `CAPACITOR-INTEGRATED FEEDTHROUGH ASSEMBLY WITH IMPROVED GROUNDING FOR AN IMPLANTABLE MEDICAL DEVICE`   A feedthrough assembly for use with implantable medical devices having a shield structure, the feedthrough assembly engaging with the remainder of the associa  
 **US20120041232A1**     OPX BIOTECHNOLOGIES INC `COMPOSITIONS AND METHODS FOR 3-HYDROXYPROPIONATE BIO-PRODUCTION FROM BIOMASS`   Methods of obtaining mutant nucleic acid sequences that d   
 **US20120105740A1**     OAKLEY INC  `EYEWEAR WITH DETACHABLE ADJUSTABLE ELECTRONICS MODULE`   A detachable adjustable electronics module may be removably or permanently connected to eyewear. The module may include electroni   
 **US20120168665A1**     NICHIAS CORP    `Biosoluble inorganic fiber`   An inorganic fiber having the following composition: 71 wt % to 80 wt % of SiO 2, 18 wt % to    
 **US20120227113A1**     NANT HOLDINGS IP LLC    `REMOTE DATA VIEWER`   A medical image and data application service provider system provides a way of remotely viewing and manipulating medical images and d   
 **US20120253494A1**     N2IT HOLDING B V    `System and Method for Controlling a Digital Audio Source`   An apparatus for signal processing, wherein a disc is p 
 **US20110017305A1**     MOGAS IND INC   `Tubular Member with Thermal Sleeve Liner`   A tubular fluid flow device of varying outside dimensions adapted for use in a high pressure, rapidly cycling temperature environment, an isolation ball valve, a ball  
 **US20120012632A1**     MITSUBOSHI DIAMOND IND CO LTD   `CUTTER AND METHOD FOR CUTTING BRITTLE MATERIAL SUBSTRATE USING SAME`   A cutter with which a diagonal crack can be created without fail deeply within a brittle material substrate is provided. The cutter has s   
 **US20120204604A1**     MIDAS SAFETY INC    `KNITTED GLOVE`   A double layer knitted glove is disclosed, the glove comprising a first yarn and a second yarn, the knitted glove comprising at least eight glove components, the components includin   
 **US20120226498A1**     MICROSOFT CORP  `MOTION-BASED VOICE ACTIVITY DETECTION`   Motion-based voice activity detection may be provided. A data stream may be received and a determi  
 **US20120131514A1**     MICROSOFT CORP  `Gesture Recognition`   Gesture recognition is described. In one example, gestures performed by a user of an input device having a touch-sensitive portion are detected using a definition of a number of regions cor   
 **US20120081389A1**     LUCIDCHART LLC  `MANIPULATING GRAPHICAL OBJECTS`   In one example, a method for rendering graphical objects on a display includes rendering each of a plurality of graphical objects within respective layers.     
 **US20120099395A1**     LOCKHEED CORP   `DETECTING STRUCTURAL CHANGES TO UNDERWATER STRUCTURES`   A method and system that can be used for scanning underwater structures. The method and system allow a user to gain a better understanding of an underwater structure. For  
 **US20120099402A1**     LOCKHEED CORP   `BUILDING A THREE-DIMENSIONAL MODEL OF AN UNDERWATER STRUCTURE`   A method and system are described that can be used for scanning underwater structures. The method and system allow a user to gain a better understand   
 **US20120101715A1**     LOCKHEED CORP   `ESTIMATING POSITION AND ORIENTATION OF AN UNDERWATER VEHICLE BASED ON CORRELATED SENSOR DATA`   A method and system are described that can be used for combining two sources of position and orientation (pose) information where the information from one source is correlated with t  
 **US20120099400A1**     LOCKHEED CORP   `ESTIMATING POSITION AND ORIENTATION OF AN UNDERWATER VEHICLE RELATIVE TO UNDERWATER STRUCTURES`   A method and system that can be used for scanning underwater structures. For example, the method and system estimate a position and ori 
 **US20120099399A1**     LOCKHEED CORP   `SONAR DATA COLLECTION SYSTEM`   A system that can be used for inspecting underwater structures. The system allows a user to gain a better understanding of the condition of an underwater structure. The system is a self-  
 **US20110261020A1**     LG DISPLAY CO LTD | LG ELECTRONICS INC  `TOUCH PANEL, METHOD FOR DRIVING TOUCH PANEL, AND DISPLAY APPARATUS HAVING TOUCH PANEL`   A touch panel includes: a substrate; a plural   
 **US20120152827A1**     KRISTAR ENTPR INC   `Bioretention System with Internal High Flow Bypass`   The invention provides a bioretention system comprising one or more cham    
 **US20110221151A1**     KOBE STEEL LTD  `AUTOMOBILE SUSPENSION PART AND MANUFACTURING OF THE SAME`   A lightweight automobile suspension part having high strength is an aluminum alloy automobile   
 **US20110186478A1**     JX NIPPON OIL & ENERGY CORP `PROCESS FOR PRODUCING NEEDLE COKE FOR GRAPHITE ELECTRODE AND STOCK OIL COMPOSITION FOR USE IN THE PROCESS`   The invention provides a stock oil composition for needle coke for a graphite electrode, the stock oil composition having a 10  
 **US20120210638A1**     INTERNAT GROWER S SUPPLY INC    `INDOOR GREENHOUSE`   Described herein is an indoor greenhouse that includes a rack unit, an outer layer that surrounds the rack unit and defines a greenhouse interior, at least one light surrounded by a l 
 **US20120094349A1**     INEOS BIO LTD   `Methods for Increasing the Production of Ethanol from Microbial Fermentation`   A stable continuous method for producing ethanol from the anaerobic bacterial fermentation of a gaseous substrate containing at least one reducing gas involves culturing in a f    
 **US20120094346A1**     INEOS BIO LTD   `METHODS FOR INCREASING THE PRODUCTION OF ETHANOL FROM MICROBIAL FERMENTATION`   A stable continuous method for producing ethanol from the anaerobic bacterial fermentation of a gaseous substrate containing at least one reducing gas involves culturing in a f    
 **US20120088284A1**     INEOS BIO LTD   `METHODS FOR INCREASING THE PRODUCTION OF ETHANOL FROM MICROBIAL FERMENTATION`   A stable continuous method for producing ethanol from anaerobic fermentation of a gaseous substrate containin   
 **US20120088283A1**     INEOS BIO LTD   `METHODS FOR INCREASING THE PRODUCTION OF ETHANOL FROM MICROBIAL FERMENTATION`   A stable continuous method for producing ethanol from anaerobic fermentation of a gaseous substrate containin   
 **US20120088282A1**     INEOS BIO LTD   `METHODS FOR INCREASING THE PRODUCTION OF ETHANOL FROM MICROBIAL FERMENTATION`   A stable continuous method for producing ethanol from anaerobic fermentation of a gaseous substrate containin   
 **US20120272942A1**     HUSQVARNA AB    `WIRE SAW`   The invention relates to a wire saw having a saw wire drive sheave ( 2) for dri 
 **US20120064984A1**     HM ATTRACTIONS INC  `LINEAR MOTOR DRIVEN AMUSEMENT RIDE AND METHOD`   A waterslide amusement ride having in a portion thereof, a linear induction motor to efficiently and effectively affe   
 **US20110306816A1**     GTC TECHNOLOGY US LLC   `HEAVY HYDROCARBON REMOVAL SYSTEMS AND METHODS`   Apparatuses and systems for removing heavy hydrocarbons from a solvent stream are disclosed herein. The apparatuses extract h   
 **US20120047080A1**     GREEN HALO SYSTEMS INC  `Waste Management and Recycling Tracking System`   An on-line waste management reporting and tracking system allows contractors to create waste management plans. Cities and other governing   
 **US20110226457A1**     GOLDEN DRAGON PRECISE COPPER TUBE GROUP INC `CONDENSATION ENHANCEMENT HEAT TRANSFER PIPE`   A condensation enhancement heat transfer pipe includes an optical pipe section, a fin section, and a transition section connecting the optical pipe section and the fin section. The outer surface of the fin section is provided with a plurality of individual fins, each 
 **US1637214A**      GODFREY CHRIST  `Elastic suspension wheel`       
 **US20120149881A1**     GENENTECH INC   `APOPTOTIC ANTI-IGE ANTIBODIES`   The present application relates to ap   
 **US20120086560A1**     GEN ELECTRIC    `OUTDOOR LIGHTING SYSTEM`   An outdoor lighting system and operating methods are prese  
 **US20120086561A1**     GEN ELECTRIC    `OUTDOOR LIGHTING SYSTEM`   An outdoor lighting system and operating methods are presented in   
 **US20110053486A1**     G CON LLC   `MODULAR, SELF-CONTAINED, MOBILE CLEAN ROOM`   Biosafety units, methods of making, and sealing the same are disclosed herein. The units comprise at least one controlled air, sealable, sterilizable cleanroom; and a mechanical system r  
 **US20120073347A1**     FORD GLOBAL TECH LLC    `System And Method For Manufacturing An F-Temper 7xxx Series Aluminum Alloy`   A system and a method of processing an F-temper alumi   
 **US20110022172A1**     ENTRIGUE SURGICAL INC   `Disposable Medical Device for Engaging with Reusable Medical Instrument and Methods of Use`   A disposable medical    
 **US20110015734A1**     ENTRIGUE SURGICAL INC   `Methods for Providing Therapy to an Anatomical Structure`   Methods for providing therapy to an anatom  
 **US20120111940A1**     DOMINION VOTING SYSTEMS CORP    `BALLOT IMAGE PROCESSING SYSTEM AND METHOD FOR VOTING MACHINES`   A ballot processing system and method processes paper ballots, such as by optically scanning or opticall    
 **US20110297311A1**     DERPROSA FILM S L   `FILM FOR THE LAMINATION OF GRAPHIC MEDIA AND PRODUCTION METHOD THEREOF`   The invention relates to a film for the lamination of graphic media, comprising an extruded p   
 **US20100269311A1**     DELSEY SOC  `SAFETY DEVICE FOR A PIECE OF LUGGAGE COMPRISING A FIRST OUTSIDE ZIPPER AND A SECOND INSIDE ZIPPER`   A safety device for a piece of luggage includes a first outside zipper ( 1) and a second insi   
 **US20110203435A1**     CONTAINER GRAPHICS CORP `Rotary Cutting Die Apparatus for Cutting Corrugated Board Including Retainers for Maintaining Trim Strippers Closely Adjacent Trim Cutting Blades`   A rotary cutting die assembly is provided that includes a die cylinder, an anvil, and a die board mounted to the d  
 **US20120114814A1**     COCA COLA CO    `METHOD OF BEVERAGE PRODUCTION, APPARATUS AND SYSTEM`   There is provided a method of regulating the formulation of a multi-component beverage comprising a beverage attribute profile, the method comprising providing a first and second comp 
 **US20120116566A1**     COCA COLA CO    `METHOD OF PRODUCTION, APPARATUS AND SYSTEM`   There is provided a method of regulating the formulation of a multi-component product comprising a product attribute profile, the method comprising providing a first and second compo  
 **US20050272398A1**     CAMBRIDGE SILICON RADIO LTD `Low voltage mixer`   A mixer comprising a pair of low frequency mixer inputs, a pair of high frequency mixer inputs, a pair of mixer outputs, four switching units, each switching unit comprising a low frequency switching unit input, a high frequency switching unit input, a switching unit output  
 **US20110099689A1**     ATG CEYLON PRIVATE LTD  `PROTECTIVE GARMENTS AND MATERIALS THEREFOR`   A method of making a garment material, comprising: providing a substrate f  
 **US20120070339A1**     AQUIONICS INC   `ULTRAVIOLET DISINFECTION OF OIL FIELD PROCESS WATER`   Methods and systems for inactivating  Desulfovibrio desulfuricans in a fracturing fluid are disclosed. The methods include exposing the fracturing fluid to a dose of   
 **US20120016678A1**     APPLE INC   `Intelligent Automated Assistant`   An intelligent automated assistant system engages with the user in an integrated, conversational manner using nat   
 **US20120094688A1**     ANDREW LLC  `System and Method for Network Timing Recovery in Communications Networks`   A system and method is disclosed for determining the network timing of a communications network from one or more mobile stations that receive signals from a    
 **US20120129944A1**     ALK AG  `STABILIZED COMPOSITION COMPRISING AT LEAST ONE ADRENERGIC COMPOUND`   A stabilised composition comprising a   
 **US20120004528A1**     ALCON RES LTD   `Implantable Remote Monitoring Sensor`   An exemplary implantable sensor includes a housing that generally conforms to a curvature   
 **US20120246273A1**     AKAMAI TECH INC `Optimal route selection in a content delivery network`   A routing mechanism operable in a distributed networking environment, such as a content delivery network (CDN), provides improved connectivity back 
 **US20120150993A1**     AKAMAI TECH INC `ASSISTED DELIVERY OF CONTENT ADAPTED FOR A REQUESTING CLIENT`   Disclosed herein are methods and apparatus facilitating delivery of web content that has adapted for particular client devices, such as mobile devices. Doing so may involve assistin   
 **US20120123701A1**     ADVANCED MECHANICAL TECH    `FORCE PLATFORM SYSTEM`   A method of processing force signals from plural force platforms includes, in a computer, in an initialization process, receiving data distinguishing the plural platforms, monitoring force data signals fro   
 **US20100244563A1**     ACLARA POWER LINE SYSTEMS INC   `UNDER FREQUENCY/UNDER VOLTAGE DETECTION IN A DEMAND RESPONSE UNIT`   A demand response unit (DRU) interposed between a utility's electrical power line (PL) and at least one load (L 1-Ln) to which power is supplied by the utility over the line. A detector (Fdet or Vdet) measures a characteristic (frequency F 
 **US20120279192A1**         `RIDING MOWER WITH A SUSPENSION COMPONENT COUPLED TO A PLURALITY OF USER SUPPORT COMPONENTS AND METHODS OF MAKING AND USING THEREOF`   In some embodiments, systems and methods provided herein relate to a riding mower including a p 
 **US20120267942A1**         `VEHICLE WHEEL BALANCE WEIGHTS`   A vehicle wheel weight for attachment to a wheel rim comprises a mass portion formed of nonlead     
 **US20120263955A1**         `RESIN COMPOSITION AND USES OF THE SAME`   A resin composition is provided. The resin composition comprises an epoxy resin and a hardener, wherei  
 **US20120246215A1**         `IDENTYING USERS OF REMOTE SESSIONS`   Systems and methods of identifying users of remote sessions are disclosed. In an    
 **US20120223477A1**         `DIE FOR USE IN GAME PLAY`   A die having at least two variable qualities that convey information for use in game p  
 **US20120221495A1**         `DIGITAL WEIGHT LOSS AID`   A health management system provides instantaneous feedback as to the relationship of food items and exercise to one's fitn  
 **US20120196516A1**         `ABRASIVE WATER JET PROCESSING MACHINE`   An abrasive water jet processing machine for jetting a fluid and performing a cutting includes a fluid supply device, an abrasive supply device, an injection pressure control  
 **US20120192937A1**         `THIN FILM STRUCTURE FOR PHOTOVOLTAIC APPLICATIONS`   A thin film structure for photovoltaic applications includes a biaxially textured metal substrate; a seed lay   
 **US20120212879A1**         `HIGH ENERGY HYBRID SUPERCAPACITORS USING LITHIUM METAL POWDERS`   A hybrid supercapacitor comprises a negative electrode made of lithium-absorbing material, a po 
 **US20120152354A1**         `SILICON-BASED SOLAR CELL WITH EUTECTIC COMPOSITION`   Growth and characterization of low cost, and high efficiency micro- and nanostructured p-n heterojunction   
 **US20120179394A1**         `Metal Detector`   The present invention provides apparatus for scanning a product to detect metal in that product. The apparatus comprises a drive coil ( 4), for generating an electrom  
 **US20120165435A1**         `ADDITIVES FOR CURABLE LIQUID COMPOSITIONS`   Transition metal complex siccatives are provided. Aspects of the siccatives 
 **US20120136617A1**         `PAVING-RELATED MEASURING DEVICE INCORPORATING A COMPUTER DEVICE AND COMMUNICATION ELEMENT THEREBETWEEN AND ASSOCIATED METHOD`   A system for determining a property of a paving-related material is provided. Such a system comprises a measuring device for selectively and directly measuring the property. A computer device is cap  
 **US20120150033A1**         `ANTIMICROBIAL ULTRASOUND TRANSMISSION GEL`   An antimicrobial ultrasound transmitting gel has an ultrasoun   
 **US20120125712A1**         `Support Membrane for Floors, Ceilings or Residential Walls`   A support membrane designed to be arranged with a covering that can be applied to bearing areas such as floors or even under and on concrete screeds for a floor is provided. Said membrane can also be used in the composition of c    
 **US20120098713A1**         `SYSTEM FOR TESTING MULTI-ANTENNA DEVICES USING BIDIRECTIONAL FADED CHANNELS`   A test system for testing multiple-input and multiple-output (MIMO) systems is provided. The test system may convey radio-frequency (RF) signals bidirectionally between a base station em  
 **US20120100813A1**         `SYSTEM FOR TESTING MULTI-ANTENNA DEVICES USING BIDIRECTIONAL FADED CHANNELS`   A test system for testing multiple-input and multiple-output (MIMO) systems is provided. The test system may convey radio-frequency (RF) signals bidirectionally between a device under test (DUT) and  
 **US20120086534A1**         `CHOKE HAVING A CORE WITH A PILLAR HAVING A NON-CIRCULAR AND NON-RECTANGULAR CROSS SECTION`   A choke includes a single-piece core entirely made of a same material, the single-piece core having two boards and a pillar located between the tw  
 **US20120073182A1**         `MULTI ARM FISHING RIG WITH FLEXIBLE ARMS`   A multi-arm fishing rig with flexible arms has been developed. The fishing rig  
 **US20120076133A1**         `System for Interconnecting Standard Telephony Communications Equipment to Internet`   Apparatus include a communication predelivery receiver, configured to communicate with and relay both IP addressed overhead and IP addressed payload data from an originating communication device. The communic    
 **US20120061153A1**         `POWER VEHICLE WITH ADJUSTABLE VELOCITY PROFILES`   Embodiments of the present invention relate to powered vehicles (e.g., lawn mowers) and, more particularly, to a control system for use with such a vehicle 
 **US20120024580A1**         `EPOXY RESIN COMPOSITION, AND PREPREG AND PRINTED CIRCUIT BOARD USING THE SAME`   Disclosed is an epoxy resin composition for printed circuit board, which includes   
 **US20120037286A1**         `PROTECTIVE BIKE COVER`   A bicycle cover and methods of using the same are disclosed. The body of the bicycle cover is two walls made of thin and flexible transparent, weather  
 **US20110278853A1**         `METHODS, SYSTEMS AND APPARATUS FOR REGULATING FREQUENCY OF GENERATED POWER USING FLYWHEEL ENERGY STORAGE SYSTEMS WITH VARYING LOAD AND/OR POWER GENERATION`   Featured are methods for regulating the AC frequency of the electrical power to be supplied on an   
 **US20110236638A1**         `Fiber-Reinforced Plastic Parts Made With Untreated Embossed Surfacing Veils With No Whitening Agents`   Untreated, embossed surfacing veils with no whitening additives can be used in a fiber-reinforced process to make   
 **US20110214246A1**         `Aeroacoustic Duster`   The aero-acoustic duster invention disclosed herein provides for high particle removal rate from surfaces with low energy expenditure relative to competing vac 
 **US20110171753A1**         `MODIFIED ANTI-HEPARIN/PF4 COMPLEX ANTIBODY AND HIT ANTIBODY STANDARD`   Provided is a modified antibody which enables the quantitative measurement of the amount of a heparin/PF    
 **US20110127364A1**         `MOBILE CREEL`   A mobile creel for organizing yarn packages and directing yarn is disclosed. In on  
 **US20110125533A1**         `Remote Scribe-Assisted Health Care Record Management System and Method of Use of Same`   The invention disclosed herein describes a health care records management system and method of use that utilizes a scribe located in a remote   
 **US20110086912A1**         `Derivatives of Propane Diyl Dicinnamate`   The present invention provides a method for treating a cancer in a subject involving administering to the subject a compoun 
 **US20100308984A1**         `VISUAL INDICATOR ADAPTOR AND ASSEMBLY FOR A TRACTOR TRAILER`   A visual indicator assembly and adaptor for a trailer includes a control circuit electrica  
 **US20080188725A1**         `OPTICAL SYSTEMS AND METHODS FOR RATIOMETRIC MEASUREMENT OF BLOOD GLUCOSE CONCENTRATION`   Novel optical devices, methods and systems relating to the detect   
 **US20080221391A1**         `DIRECT DRIVE INSTRUMENTS AND METHODS OF USE`   Disclosed herein are various instruments, systems, and methods of use. The instruments can have v